# Has anyone used the ruby avro sample_ipc_http_client.rb to talk to a Java implemented avro server?

Tags: java, ruby, avro

I've been trying to make this setup work but when I make a request to the avro-1.7.1 server I get an

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `read_nonblock': end of file reached (EOFError)
```

On the server side I'm seeing the below message. The avro server is running on Netty-3.4.0:

```
WARN ipc.NettyServer: Unexpected exception from downstream.
```

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I have a protocol/schema describing the request I'm trying to make:

```
"messages" : {
    "ping" : {
    "request" : [ ],
    "response" : "boolean"
}
```

And per the http_client example my request is loading my protocol which it parses fine and my request is now:

```
result = requestor.request('ping',{})
```

Has anyone gotten Ruby client to talk to a Java avro server? Thanks for any help!

Comment: did you find some answer for your question?

Comment: I've been a bad stackoverflow denizen, no luck. Though we decided to go another way, so this issue is moot.